# How to use moodle with a locally installed copy of mathjax

Tags: filter, moodle, equation, mathjax, lms

I am having a hardtime getting moodle to work with a locally installed mathjax instead of the mathjax cdn.

I followed instructions from https://github.com/maths/moodle-qtype_stack/blob/master/doc/en/Installation/Mathjax.md and below is what I did.

I downloaded a copy of mathjax 2.7.9, unpack, renamed and then placed in moodle/lib. Opened the test pages to ensure all is working as intended, then i edited cdn url in file settings.php located moodle/filter/mathjaxloader from what was there to http://localhost/moodle/lib/mathjax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML. With all of the above steps taken, filter has refuse to display any equation but instead displays math error.